# Android Device Password Policy erased on Reboot

Tags: android, android-broadcast, device-policy-manager, android-reboot

I am using DevicePolicyManager class in Android to set a password policy from my device admin application.

I noticed that on reboot, the password policy is erased. For example, if minimum length of the password was set to 5, after reboot it is reset to 0.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. How are you testing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare if you reboot and try to reset your pin for example, it doesn't restrict you to use the minimum length you set earlier. Which means the restriction is gone.